# How to make each element in a list another list in python

Tags: python

I have a list inside a loop for e.g

```
A=[25,45,34,....87]
```

in the next iteration A should be

```
A=[[25,32],[45,13],[34,65],....[87,54]]
```

in the next iteration A should be

```
A=[[25,32,44],[45,13,67],[34,65,89],....[87,54,42]]
```

and so on.How can i do that?is it possible?The code i am working on is

```
    s=0
    e=25
    for i in range(0,4800):
        if not m_list_l:
            m_list_l.append(max(gray_sum[s:e]))
        m_list_l[i].append(max(gray_sum[s:e]))
        s+=25
        e+=25
```

But this give me Error as

```
m_list_l[i].append(max(gray_sum[s:e]))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Where are these extra elements coming from?

Comment: What should `m_list_l[i].append()` do before there are nested lists?

Comment: @pvg gray_sum is another large list

Comment: @Natecat i declared m_list_l as an empty list in the beginning of the program

Comment: It's not clear where the extra elements are coming from and what `gray_sum` and `m_list_l` are. Can you update your question to include a runnable example that produces the error?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim It isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Natecat It is totally relevant. Without knowing the the structure of `gray_sum`, this question is not complete and unclear what the behavior is

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Except the behavior is irrelevant, because his error is caused by the code given, meaning his problem can be solved completely without knowledge of those blackbox functions. `max` returns a single value, not a list.

Comment: @Natecat: As question says *"How to make each element in a list another list in python"* and OP has shared some expected behavior with the desired result. Even after fixing the exception, you can not be sure that the code will give you the right result without knowing the content of `gray_sum `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element you insert should be a list, not an int. Change `m_list_l.append(max(gray_sum[s:e]))` to `m_list_l.append([max(gray_sum[s:e])])` to fix this.

Comment: Thank you very much..Worked fine.I changed the declaration to 'm_list_l= [[x] for x in range(0,4800)]' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Say there are two lists as

```
A = [i for i in range(10,100,10)]
A
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

B = [i for i in range(20,100,10)]
B
[20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

The combined list would be

```
L = [[i,j] for i,j in zip(A,B)]
L
 [[10, 20],
 [20, 30],
 [30, 40],
 [40, 50],
 [50, 60],
 [60, 70],
 [70, 80],
 [80, 90],
 [90, 100]]
```

Comment: `list(zip(A,B))` will do the same. You do not need list comprehension to achieve this